# How can I use Option type as path pram in playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to use an Option type as path param in routes file to call an action method in controller-

in routes file

```
GET /test/:x/:y       controllers.TestController.test(x:Int, y:Option[Int])
```

in controller -

```
def test(x:Int,y:Option[Int])=Action{. . . .}
```

but my compiler says me -

```
 implement an implicit PathBindable for this type..
```

How can I do this for Option Type ?

Comment: If you're going to have an optional parameter, I'd recommend making it a query parameter rather than part of the path.

Comment: Eg, the URL would be `URL/test/ABC?y=DEF` rather than `URL/test/ABC/DEF`.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley, thanks a lot :)